# Decode AMQP message as a Map using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I have to decode AMQP message using Spring. To handle it I now use:

```
    // Configure queue. 
    RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(cf);
    Queue queue = new Queue(queueName);
    admin.declareQueue(queue);
    FanoutExchange exchange = new FanoutExchange(exchangeName);
    admin.declareExchange(exchange);
    admin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange));  

    // set up the listener and container
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);

    MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(listener);
    container.setMessageListener(adapter);
    container.setQueueNames(queueName);
    container.start();
```

And my Listener is

```
public class DataListener {

    public void handleMessage(Object incomingMessage) {
        LOGGER.error("AMQP: got message.{}", incomingMessage);
    }   

}
```

The message is sent using convertAndSend method of AmqpTemplate. No configuration was given to AmqpTemplate, everything is by default.

How I can possibly receive my incomingMessage as a HashMap of fields? I do not want to strongly couple it to particular object type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean your message is a POJO bean...

Use JSON - on the outbound side use a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` instead of the default `SimpleMessageConverter`, which uses Java serialization.

On the receiving side, the same JSON converter will try to convert the incoming stream to the original POJO.

To avoid that, configure the JSON message converter to map the class name to a HashMap instead of the original POJO.

You can do that by providing the converter with a custom `DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper` that is configured to map the class name from the `__TypeId__` header to `java.util.HashMap`.

**EDIT**

Or you can simply inject a `ClassMapper` that always returns `HashMap` - here's a quick boot App I wrote to illustrate the technique:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So36837736Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So36837736Application.class, args);
        context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class).convertAndSend(new Foo("bar"));
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate template(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey(queue().getName());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueues(queue());
        MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(new Object() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void handleMessage(Map<String, Object> map) {
                System.out.println("\n\n\n" + map + "\n\n\n");
            }

        });
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        ClassMapper classMapper = new ClassMapper() {

            @Override
            public void fromClass(Class<?> clazz, MessageProperties properties) {
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> toClass(MessageProperties properties) {
                return HashMap.class;
            }

        };
        messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);
        adapter.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        container.setMessageListener(adapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new AnonymousQueue();
    }

    public static class Foo {

        private final String bar;

        private Foo(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

    }

}
```